# MHT file generation using Redemption

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

We are generating mht file using Redemption dll in C#.net.

We are getting body part from .msg using rdoMail.HTMLBody..and create mht file using this value.

But created mht file not able to print using word instance..or word can not able to open it with data written after < body> tag.

find sample mht file having issue with word instance,
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B12pIBigSgsfdThQTTZXelp3UWM

Is there any resolution for this kind of issue, as the html body return by rdoMail.HTMLBody property having that < body> and < html> tags which ends before Disclaimer content of Mail..

Note: We are using word 2013.

Find attached image file having reference of PR_HTML value..

Thanks[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply create an MHTML file using `RDOMail.SaveAs(.., olMHTML)`?

Comment: Why are you adding anything after the closing body tag? Or, even worse, after the closing html tag?

Comment: We are not adding anything after the closing tag, we are appending the same value which will return by rdoMail.HTMLbody property.. we have also try with RdoMail.SaveAs(..,olMHTML) but issue still the same...Word can not able to open it and there are content present after end of body and html tags

Comment: Are you saying RDOMail.HTMLBody returns a string with data after the closing body tag?

Comment: Yes Dimitry, body content from RDOMail.HTMLBody having data after </Body> tag

Comment: Is that the same data you see in PR_HTML: property in OutlookSpy (click IMessage button)?

Comment: Yes Dimitry, i have verified using same Property, attaching image file in original post for same infromation which i verified..

Comment: So the problem is with the original email, right? How was it created?

Comment: Not sure how original email created, we have extracted that message from client PST.